# C++ for graphical software

Tags: c++

I'm in the process of learning C++ and was wondering about the graphical implications of C++.

I know Chrome was developed in C++, but I don't see how to replicate it or create any sort of GUI.

How is Chrome programmed for the UI?

Comment: Well, the Chrome is based [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/), which is open source. You can have a look :)

Comment: You may want to read [what you can ask here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) befor posting such overly broad question.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't include any graphical library in it. So you need to use any existing third-party library or API of operating system.

For example, there exists next graphical libraries, which supports C++:

1. MFC
2. Qt
3. wxWidgets
4. TCL/Tk
5. GTK+

Some of them are object oriented and some - not. Some of them are portable, some - not. Some of them are proprietary, some - not.

Also you always can use low-level API's such as Win32 API

Comment: Is this how chrome was made?

Comment: You may want to add [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org) and [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org) to that list :)